# How to deal with relational entity mapping in AutoMapper?

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

Our Entity model has navigation properties:

```
public class Course
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public Guid InstructorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Instructor Instructor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Coinstructors { get; set; }
}
```

That is, a course have one instructor and multiple coinstructors.

My view model has the id's of those instructors.

```
public class CourseCreateModel
{
    ...
    public InstructorModel Instructor { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<InstructorModel> Coinstructors { get; set; }
}
```

The `InstructorModel` contains the `Id`:

```
 public class InstructorModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

To make the data transfer from our DTO `CourseCreateModel` into the domain model `Course`, we can map the instructor easily because there is a `InstructorId` in the domain model:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CourseCreateModel, Course>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.InstructorId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Instructor.Id))

    ...;
```

But how to map `Coinstructors`? We can get an array of coinstructor's id. But how to do the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two options:

**Option nr. 1 :**

```
.ForMember(c=>c.Coinstructors,op=>op.MapFrom(v=>v.Coinstructorids.Select(c=>new Instructor(){Id=c})))
```

where `Coinstructorids = List<int>();`

**Option nr. 2:**

Create an custom resolver:

```
public class CustomConvert : ValueResolver<IList<int>, IList<Instructor>>
    {
        protected override string ResolveCore(IList<int> source)
        {
            string result = new List<Instructor>();
            foreach (var item  in source)
            {
                result.Add(new Instructor() {Id = item});
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

and the use it :

```
 .ForMember(c => c.Coinstructors, op => op.ResolveUsing<CustomConvert>().FromMember(c => c.Coinstructorids));
```

where `Coinstructorids = List<int>();`